# Eclipse freezes on loading workbench after installing SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-mountain-lion, eclipse-juno

I have just downloaded the eclipse installer for Java developer on eclipse.org

I had no problem to run it, but after installing the SVn on it, I can't open eclipse anymore.

It hangs on loading workbench everytime (and eclipse is not responding). I have to kill the process.

I tried several things such as deleting some files in the .metadata folder, but nothing changed

What can I do to use it with the SVN client?

(Eclipse Juno, Mac OS X Moutain Lion)

Thank you

Comment: Which SVN client did you install?

Comment: JavaHL 1.6/1.7, and SVN eclipse Kit

Comment: Which SVN plugin for Eclipse, Subclipse or Subversive? (they both use JavaHL and svnkit)

Comment: I went into Install new software --> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno, and in Collaboration I took the 5 subversive SVN

Comment: Oh, right...I forgot that's now an Eclipse project and included in Juno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install JavaHL on your Computer. I think that's the problem. Here is some info from the [website](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-7498d204a5be83e0e97d196ba75fc797d5f0c822)

> OSX comes with a SVN command line client, but unfortunately they do
>   not include the JavaHL library.
>
> The best thing to do is to install one of the OSX package managers for
>   open-source software, such as MacPorts or HomeBrew. If you are doing
>   software development on OSX, you are going to eventually want or need
>   different open-source Unix applications. So it is worth the effort to
>   set one of these up and they make it easy for you to get Subversion
>   and always have the latest version. You will also have easy access to
>   other open source applications via similar simple commands.
>
> For MacPorts, the commands to run are:
>
> sudo port install subversion-javahlbindings +no_bdb +universal For
>   HomeBrew the command is:
>
> brew install --universal --java subversion Pay attention to any
>   post-install instructions related to creating a symlink in
>   /Library/Java/Extensions. You need to follow these instructions so
>   that the JavaHL library is available by default to the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

There is a partial work-around here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388170#c14

You need to put this line:

-Djava.awt.headless=true

somewhere in the eclipse.ini file (at the end is OK).

On my machine eclipse.ini is found here:

/Applications//eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini

Some issues with MDT/papyrus are mentioned in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388170#c17

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works. But you can give it a try.

Open eclipse.ini in eclipse folder and change `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M` to some bigger value like `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 512M`.

This increases the memory allocated to the eclipse process. However, be sure that processes other than eclipse don't load the computer.

Comment: Note that XXMaxPermSize only increases permgen and not the general heap that Eclipse has - it would surprise me if 512M permgen is required for Eclipse to Start. For heap, use -Xmx512m (substituting 512 for another value as needed, likely 1024 or higher), this value is at the bottom of my eclipse.ini file but it may vary